# how to import a publish profile in visual studio mac

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-mac

I cannot see my app service by default in the *Publish* menu, because I have two subscriptions and the default one is not the one with the app service I need. Since there is no option there to change subscriptions, nor to import a profile, I can only create a new app service.

There I can switch the subscription to see my service exists, as it is already taken by trying to use the name.

I have the downloaded profile -- there really must be some way to *give it* the profile, maybe manually (on the terminal). How can I do that?

Comment: I think that if you create a new .pubxml file with the correct information for your subscription in the Properties/PublishProfiles directory then Visual Studio for Mac will pick it up and display it in the Publish menu. You may need to close and re-open the solution for it to appear.

Comment: My answer is VS on windows. Because I haven't used VS on mac, I'm not sure if their layout is consistent. The answers given are for your reference, I hope to help you.:)

Comment: VS Mac does not support creating or editing custom publish profiles itself currently.

Comment: there's a comment in official the feature request system from a developer that it was being developed in 2017, and another that it was ready for the next release from early 2019. I wonder why it didnt make it in

Comment: @MattWard feel free to post your initial comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to publish my web using a partial solution from Matt Ward but not only:

> I think that if you create a new .pubxml file with the correct
> information for your subscription in the Properties/PublishProfiles
> directory then Visual Studio for Mac will pick it up and display it in
> the Publish menu. You may need to close and re-open the solution for
> it to appear. – Matt Ward Feb 13 at 16:31

1. Copy PublishProfile.xml to Properties/PublishProfiles
2. Solution -> publish ( my case Visual studio didn't pick my settings * ) Publish to Azure.
3. Select the correct Service on Azure and hit publish.

**Even when I tried Windows solution, like restart Visual Studio and other normal solution for Windows.*